# ASP.NET MVC Apply web.config transformss on "Publish"

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, deployment, web-config, release

I'm using VS2010 and I have a Web application that I deploy using the "Publish" command.

I have defined a couple of transformations in the Web.Release.Config file to change the connection string and other settings that need to change in the "live" server.

The problem I'm seeing is that when I execute the "Publish" command it doesn't apply the transformations defined in the web.release.config file.

Any idea on how to achieve this?

Thanks

Comment: tugberk has a great suggestion, but it might help if you posted the relevent portions of your web.config and your transforms to see if the problem is in your transform definition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On visual studio, there should be a select box top on the menu. You need to select the type of your build (Release, Debug, etc.).

Something like below :

[image]

Be careful that it is set to Release.

Comment: That was it, I thought the "Publish" action automatically selected Release, changed that and it worked. Thanks

Comment: @willvv well, I have been there once :) glad that it helped.